# "Ask question" button hard to find

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I found it easier to find the "submit yours [picture]" link than the "ask question" link.

- The former is where I'd expect the latter to be.
- The former is larger and more prominent than the latter.

I know, I should've complained before the design went live. Sorry.

Comment: There's a "submit yours [picture]" link? /me hunts...

Comment: @bacar There used to be :)

Answer (score 7):

I agree -- same problem on math.se , the "ask question" link needs more aggressive styling (color, etc) to make it not look like "just another link".

Answer (score 4):

I know that at one point in the history of Stack Overflow (which this site is based on), there was a problem with the 'Ask a Question' button being too easy to find, resulting in people posting low-quality questions (ie, the questions were poorly worded, poorly researched, etc).

I don't know if this was a motivating factor in this site's design, to down-play the Ask link.  I don't think this community has a problem with many drive-by askers, so I agree, the Ask link should be more prominent.  If we end up having a problem down the line, perhaps we can revisit this then.

Comment: The "ask question" is now in a different colour -- do you think that'd help?

Comment: @Rowland, better but not quite good enough. :)